# How to set SubjectAltName in Java program

Tags: java, bouncycastle, csr

I have below java code to generate CSR but I am not sure how to add SubjectAltNames in below code. Suppose if I want to add two SANs here like `a1.example.ca` and `a2.example.ca`. Please help where and how to add SubjectAltName in below program.

```java
public static void createCSR() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, OperatorCreationException, IOException {
    Provider bc = new
    org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.insertProviderAt(bc, 1);
    KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    gen.initialize(2048);

    KeyPair pair = gen.generateKeyPair();
    PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
    PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();

    X500Principal subject = new X500Principal("C=CN, ST=ON, L=Brmpt, O=loblaw, OU=network, CN=abc.example.ca, EMAILADDRESS=john.adam@test.ca");

    ContentSigner signGen = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").build(privateKey);

    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder builder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(subject, publicKey);

    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = builder.build(signGen);
    OutputStreamWriter output = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
    PEMWriter pem = new PEMWriter(output);
    pem.writeObject(csr);
    pem.writeObject(privateKey);
    pem.close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an attribute to the PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder requesting the set of extensions you want on the certificate:

```
//import org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers;
//import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
//import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extensions;
//import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralName;
//import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralNames;

GeneralName[] subjectAltNames = new GeneralName[]{
    new GeneralName(GeneralName.dNSName, "a1.example.ca"),
    new GeneralName(GeneralName.dNSName, "a2.example.ca")
};

Extension[] extensions = new Extension[] {
    Extension.create(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, true, new GeneralNames(subjectAltNames))
};

builder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest, new Extensions(extensions));
```